# Quicksort in JavaScript and Java

Tags: javascript, java, quicksort

I just found a strange problem. I tried to use JavaScript to implement a quicksort based on code written in Java, however, the result was not what I expected.
Java code :

```
public class Sort {
    public static void main (String[] args){
        int[] number = {1,10,2,2,2,3,5,7,8,2};
        for (int i = 0; i < number.length ; i++) {
            System.out.println(quickSort(number)[i]);//1,2,2,2,2,3,5,7,8,10
        }
    }
    static int[] quickSort(int[] number){
        int length = number.length;
        int start = 0;
        int end = length -1;
        number = quick_sort (start,end,number);
        return number;
    }
    private static int[] quick_sort(int start,int end,int[] number) {

        int pivot = number[(start+end)/2];
        int s = start;
        int e = end;
        while (s <= e) {
            while(number[s] < pivot) {
                s++;
            }
            while(number[e] > pivot) {
                e--;
            }
            //swap the value
            if (s <= e) {
                int temp = number[s];
                number[s] = number[e];
                number[e] = temp;
                //move both sides cursor
                s++;
                e--;
            }

        }

        // recursively sorting lower half
        if (start < e) {
            quick_sort(start, e, number);
        }
        //recursively sorting higher half
        if (end > s) {
            quick_sort(s, end, number);
        }
        return number;
    }
}
```

JavaScript :

```
function main() {
    var numbers  = [1,10,2,2,2,3,5,7,8,2];
    var length = numbers.length;
    var start = 0;
    var end = length - 1;
    alert(quickSort(start, end, numbers));//2,3,5,8,7,2,1,2,2,10  <----- not sorted
}

function quickSort(start, end, numbers) {
    var s,e,temp,pivot;
    s = start;
    e = end;
    pivot = numbers[(start+end)/2];
    while(s<=e){
        while(numbers[s] < pivot ) {
            s++;
        }
        while(numbers[e] > pivot) {
            e--;
        }
        if(s<=e) {
            temp = numbers[s];
            numbers[s] = numbers[e];
            numbers[e] = temp;
            e--;
            s++;
        }
    }
    if(start < e) {
        quickSort(start, e, numbers);
    }
    if(end > s) {
        quickSort(s, end, numbers);
    }
    return numbers;
}
main();
```

Code written in Java gives the result of 1,2,2,2,2,3,5,7,8,10, in the other hard, code written in JavaScript produces the result of 2,3,5,8,7,2,1,2,2,10, which is different from original array but still not sorted correctly. Any thoughts about this? Thanks in advance

Edit:

Thanks for the responses, I was looking into logic rather than basics.

Comment: What's your debugger telling ?

Comment: Well one problem is that Java lets you program with explicit integers, while JavaScript does not. That'd be the first thing I'd look at.

Comment: no error message was produced :-(

Comment: `(start+end)/2` isn't necessarily an integer in JS.

Comment: @AndyTurner  good point!  How stupid I was :-(,   just learning JavaScript

Comment: @XuzhengWang  it's far more stupid, to label a mistake like not noticing that "(start+end)/2 isn't necessarily an integer in JS"    as "stupid", than it is to make the mistake

Comment: @barlop that's a pretty complicated koan :)

Comment: I don't know what you want to do, if it is just by curiosity or not, but [`Array.prototype.sort()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) would be far more efficient in Javascript...

Comment: @XuzhengWang don't beat yourself up, it's pretty subtle, especially if you are copying and pasting the java code into JS. I only spotted it because of Pointy's comment (but I am not really a JS programmer...).

Comment: @JuniusRendel   Thanks for your suggestion, I was just trying to practice my JavaScript and improve my familiarity of it by implementing algorithms

Comment: @Pointy yeah.. I should've just said "to label that mistake as stupid, is more stupid than making the mistake".   In fact, to make that mistake, is normal, not stupid at all, but to label that mistake as stupid, is profoundly stupid. It takes stupidity to new levels. It wouldn't surprise me if the OP thought debuggers exist only for stupid programmers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`(start+end)/2` isn't necessarily an integer in JS. It works with `Math.floor((start+end)/2)`.